# Python SimpleBlobDetector.detect() is very slow with big images and can crash

Tags: python, opencv

I program in Python 3.X and use the opencv simple blob detector to retrieve their key points. This works very good. However when it comes to big images - like really big e.g. 16384x16384 pixels - processing takes really long. Here is the code:

```
...
if blur_sigma > 0:
  img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (-1, -1), blur_sigma)
else:
  img_blurred = img
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img_filtered = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, tuple(lower_bounds), tuple(upper_bounds))

ksize = 2 * morph_size + 1
morph_element = cv2.getStructuringElement(morph_element, (ksize, ksize))
img_morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(img_filtered,
                               morph_operator,
                               morph_element,
                               borderType=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)

blob_params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
blob_params.filterByInertia = False
blob_params.minConvexity = 0.0
blob_detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(blob_params)
key_points = blob_detector.detect(img_morphed)
...
```

Additionally happened several times that in the last line, during execution, an assertion is thrown which directed me there:

> cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:433: error: (-215) u != 0 in function cv::Mat::create

In there, an allocation fails.

So my questions are: 
1) Is this kind of image size an edge case where the detection simply can no longer work with reasonable time? 
2) Is the error also related to the image size? 
3)Is there a way to improve detection with additional steps beforehand?

Thanks!

Comment: 16384*16384/1024/1024 = 256.0M, too large

Comment: Maybe you can scale the image down to a smaller size to get rough idea where blobs are, then zoom back in on likely areas for accurate detection. Maybe you can split the image across multiple processors/machines, detect blobs and re-assemble.

Comment: You can try to reduce the min/max threshold to have a smaller range, this can speed it up, but the image is quite big, it may be that is too much... maybe it is even running out of memory?

Comment: api55: It did happen that it ran out of memory - I posted the error in my post.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Hmm and how can I accomplish your suggestions? I am not really sure how I should do that.

Comment: What is the average size of a blob you are hoping to find?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Hmm I have no limitation in this direction. Currently I configure the SimpleBlobDetector with params that tell him to use no limits at all.

Comment: What do you mean by *"you have no limitation"*? I meant to look at your image, find some blobs by eye and tell me what sort of size they are.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Ok. This can vary between blobs being around smaller than 100x100, 500x200, 1000x1200, 3000x400 etc and everything in between.

Comment: So, what I mean to say is, if you resized your 16,000x16,000 pixel image down to 4,000x4,000 it would take 1/16th of the memory and your smallest blobs would still be 25x25 and big enough to find.